# Application.Run Syntax Error with arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro.xlsm file containing a `Sub Generation(i As Integer)`.

In another file I want to call it with `Application.Run ("macro.xlsm'!Generation", 1)` but it says Compile Error: Expected: =

The line also appeared in red in the editor.

I tried to remove the argument from the Sub and from the call and it works perfectly. Any idea what's wrong here ?

Comment: Sounds like one of them is a `Function` instead of a `Subroutine`

Comment: Remove the parentheses. You use  parentheses when you are setting a variable calling a function for example, directly running a procedure doesn't need them.

Comment: Nice, I removed the parentheses and it works. I've tried it but without the "," before the argument

Comment: Try Application.Run "macro.xlsm!Generation”, 1